# wxpython : Add Background picture and buttons

Tags: python, wxpython

I am fairly new to `wxPython` and is trying to place some button over an background image. I was unable to find a container in `wxPython` that can contain an image and, on top of it some buttons. I am using the below code hence:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
        self.frame = parent

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        button1 = wx.Button(self, label='Button1', pos=(100, 100), size=(175, 28))
        sizer.Add(button1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.TOP, 100)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 0, wx.ALL, 75)
        self.SetSizer(hSizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
        """
        Add a picture to the background
        """
        # yanked from ColourDB.py
        dc = evt.GetDC()

        if not dc:
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
            rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
            dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
        dc.Clear()
        bmp = wx.Bitmap("admin.png")
        dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)


########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(320, 243))
        panel = MainPanel(self)        
        self.Center()

########################################################################
class Main(wx.App):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        dlg = MainFrame()
        dlg.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    app.MainLoop()
```

But the issue that `button1` is not getting placed properly - no matter whatever I am setting the 
`pos=(100, 100), size=(175, 28)` values- it gets placed in same location (?)

Also I do no want the maximize, minimize and restore button options - probably only a button to close the window - how can I remove the default maximize, minimize and restore button from the frame / application window?

=======UPDATE=======

Below is the exact image with text and buttons I need to create the GUI interface - I tried a lot to create buttons same like that or graphics like this but I am unable - I have already posted the code - please let me know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an article on putting a background image on a panel, which should work for your use case as well. You can read it here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/

For removing the various buttons in the title bar, you'll need to mess with the frame's style flags. This other thread talks a bit about that:

- http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/How-can-I-disable-the-Maximise-Minimise-Button-td2363025.html

The example there shows the following code:

```
frame = wx.Frame( None, title="Hello wxPython", style = wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CAPTION | wx.RESIZE_BORDER )
```

That should get you pretty close to what you want.

Comment: I have attached the the exact image with text and buttons I need to create the GUI interface - I tried a lot to create buttons same like that or graphics like that but I am unable - I have already posted the code - please let me know how I can achieve this?

Comment: You would use the code I mentioned in the first tutorial to apply the image to the panel's background. To create buttons like that, you'll probably want to look at the GradiantButton or the ShapedButton widgets. You can either position them absolutely using x/y coordinates or use sizers with spacers in them.